# Remove html tags from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am developing an application for iphone which needs to load some description to a `UIWebView`. But text that loads into the `UIWebView` shows some html tags like `<p></p>`.Is there any way to remove these type of tags?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some or all tags?  If you put the text into a file with a .html extension does it render properly in a web browser?  Does it have all the proper tags such as <html>...</html>?

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question the other day and got some good responses. I imagine one of these could suit your needs.

[anyway to delete all <a href=> tags with javascript after the page loads on an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216798/anyway-to-delete-all-a-href-tags-with-javascript-after-the-page-loads-on-an-ip/3220041#3220041)

Hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer and is exactly what you are looking for ...

Write the following script in the webView delegate method. ( UIWebviewdidfinishLoading)

```
NSString *myText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];
```