# anyway to delete all <a href=> tags with javascript after the page loads on an iPad?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ipad, uiwebview

I know that I can run a line of javascript code after the page loads on an iPad with UIWebView (which is what I am using), but I do not know what I could type to go through and remove all of the  tags. I also would like to be able to do this to only certain parts of the page e.g. only remove  tags within a certain  tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get all elements by tag name using [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName). All links have the tag name `a`. You can visually remove them by setting their `display` style to `none`.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

To remove elements of a certain tag within a certain tag, just invoke `getElementsByTagName()` on the element in question. Suppose that you want to hide all links inside a `<li>` only:

```
var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
    var anchors = listitems[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++) {
        anchors[j].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)` is also a good one, but it doesn't work nicely inside a standard `for` loop. You need to loop **backwards**:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = elements.length; i-- > 0;) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

---

**Update** as per the clarified functional requirement: you thus want to *replace* the link element with a text node representing the link's original content? You can use [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:element.replaceChild) for this. Here's a kickoff example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = elements.length; i-- > 0;) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var text = document.createTextNode(element.firstChild.nodeValue);
    element.parentNode.replaceChild(text, element);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the author would want to preserve the anchor tags' content (display text, images, what have you) when removing the links.

Comment: @eye: hmm, that makes sense. I'd instead just change their `href` to `javascript:void(0)` and add a `style` which makes the links look like plain text (default text color, no underline, default cursor). @Matthew: please let us know what you *actually* want. Maybe I'll bring a code example in.

Comment: i definitely would like to keep the items there, just no longer make them clickable or look like links. Instead of a link existing, it would just look like plaintext. 

Thank you for all of your help already!

Comment: @BalusC I would love to see a script written like that.

Comment: Added an example (which does it the better way than I first had in mind).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This now led me to a different problem. The place I want to execute this code on is inside of an iframe, I cannot see the original HTML code. Any other options?

Comment: You can get the iframe's `document` by `iframeElement.document` and then use it further.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post a remove() function to complement BalusC:

```
function remove(el){
   if(el.parentNode)el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

Note: If the element doesn't have a parent, it means it is not in the DOM tree.
It also means it will be removed in the GC's (garbage collector) next run (as long as there are no references to it).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing a lot of dom manipulation, it might be worth it to include jQuery to grab your elements. It'd be a little easier to remove items. Eg.

```
$(function(){
   $('.surrounding_class a').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove links but preserve their display contents (text, images, etc.) you can insert their `childNodes` before the links, then remove the link elements:

```
var removeLinks = function(context) {
    var undefined;
    if(context === undefined) {
        context = document;
    }
    if(!context) {
        return false;
    }
    var links = context.getElementsByTagName('a'), i, link, children, j, parent;
    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        link = links[i];
        parent = link.parentNode;
        if(!link.href) {
            continue;
        }

        children = link.childNodes;
        for(j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
            parent.insertBefore(children[j], link);
        }
        parent.removeChild(link);
    }
    return context;
};

// Use:
removeLinks(document.getElementById('container'));
```